# Laravel filtering result after query

Tags: php, laravel

ich have a query on my database where i get all profiles that are over
25, but i want to filter my result again after this query with different parameters.
For example which profile is male or female, single , in love , relationship etc.

Because i have a lot of different querys on my result, i tried first to build a switch statement.
But this is growing with the time and it is not really the best option for good code i think.
Can annonye help me to get a better way for my problem ?

Model:

```
public static function getProfilesOverTweentyFive()
{
  return static::where(['age' > 25]);
}
```

Controller:

```
// Filtering the Result
public function filterList($key)
{
    switch($key)
    {
            case 'male':
                 return $filter = array('gender' , '=', 'male');
                 break;
            case 'female':
                 return $filter = array('gender' , '=', 'female');
                 break;
            case '10':
                 return $filter = array('looking', 'LIKE', '%Man%');
                 break;

            case '10':
                 return $filter = array('looking', 'LIKE', '%Women%');
                 break;

                 // etc 
          }         

       }        

         // Show the filtering Result       
         public function show()
         {
          $filter   = Input::get('filter');
          $column   = $this->filterList($filter)[0];
          $operator = $this->filterList($filter)[1];
          $key      = $this->filterList($filter)[2];

          $profileList = Profile::getProfilesOverTweentyFive()->where($column,$operator,$key)->paginate(15);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) just add a scope for each query in your eloquent model

```
public function scopeMale($query)
{
    return $query->where('gender', '=', 'male');
}
public function scopeOverTwentyFive($query)
{
    return $query->where('age', '>', 25);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$users = App\User::male()->overTwentyFive()->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed for your idea, but i have tweenty different filter queries, and i think my controller and model get overloaded with this solution.

Comment: in the end the query builder is going to execute the same sql query. The advantage of using scopes is to keep the code readable and more organized